# Migrate fails Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, migration

So i decided to try out Laravel since i heard it's a great framework similar to Rails etc.
However i got stuck in the very basic first parts of creating my testapplikation. When i try to create a migration file i get errors.

```
php artisan migrate:make create_users_table


Parse error: parse error in /myfolders/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php on line 411
```

Anyone have any ideas?
I probably should mention i don't have Composer installed cause i just want to focus on creating a basic Laravel project.

Comment: Please write the code of your `create_users_table` migration so we can try to find the error

Comment: The migration file is not being created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upgrade your PHP version, Laravel 4 requires `PHP >= 5.4`.

Comment: Im running MAMP that uses version 5.4.4

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using ?

Comment: I just downloaded it so i figured it was the latest. If i run `laravel --version` it says 1.0.0 though(?). Problem is i cant run any `php artisan` commands ,always get that parse error

Comment: Please try `php artisan --version` to show the version

Comment: Can not run that command. It gives me the same parse error as above. My OSX php version is 5.3.8. But im using MAMP, and the server works and has php version 5.4.4. What am i missing here?

Comment: The MAMP version is used when your request pages using the browser. but on terminal, your client version is used ! please upgrade it to 5.4 to solve the problem

Comment: Thank you for your advices! I updated my PHP version and now it's working.